# React import, export behavior

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
import React from 'react';
import PopupPlaylist from "./popup-playlist.jsx";
import YouTubeGetter from './youtube-getter.jsx';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
import $ from 'jquery';
import _ from 'underscore';

class PlayerContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    // YouTubeGetter is not available here
    // But you can do <FontAwesome ...?>
    debugger
```

After reviewing the available documents, I don't understand why the variable `YouTubeGetter` is undefined at the bottom. The module that's being imported looks like this.

```
class YouTubeGetter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.getVideoId = this.getVideoId.bind(this);
    this.getSongInfos = this.getSongInfos.bind(this);
  }

  ... 

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default YouTubeGetter;
```

Comment: But you can do *<YouTubeGetter/>*? Sometimes the transpiled code and the debugger not work very well. Because YouTubeGetter could be transpiled to something like this _YouTubeGetter or whatever the transpiler choose.

Comment: Also are your paths correct?

Comment: So basically this should work. Can you enhance your demo code and show how you want to access the YouTubeGetter in the PlayerContainer Component? And furthermore add the imports to the YouTubeGetter class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not a problem with the code, but I was debugging it wrong.

When you simply put a debugger statement there and check for the `YouTubeGetter` variable, the variable does not exist because it's been garbage collected by the compiler as it was never referenced. If you put `var x = new YouTubeGetter()` above the debugger statement, you can access `x` without a problem.